# best practice for k8s webhook service

Tags: kubernetes

Is it a recommended way to use webhook to inject sidecar container? If yes, webhook service must be very stable. If webhook has something wrong, It will be a disaster, as it can not create pod any more. So there are some other best practice?

Comment: Can you elaborate on a use case for this? Why you don't add the sidecar container from the beginning as part of the deployment?

Comment: I use [openkruise](https://github.com/openkruise/kruise) framework to inject sidecar container,  kruise use webhook to inject, so webhook is very important. why not add sidecar container as part of the deployment, because i want to upgrade sidecar container alone and don't want to restart business container.